# Need assistance on using for loop to display my array

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, for-loop

I'm aware of the C++11 way of doing this, but I'm told to use the "traditional" way.

Anyways here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int items[ 5 ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  cout << "items before modification: ";
  for( unsigned int whatever = 0; whatever < sizeof(items); whatever++ )
  {
    cout << items[ whatever ] << " ";
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
items before modification: 1 2 3 4 5 1 -1073949596 -1073949588 -1073949744 -1217175552 0 0 -1218570461 134514560 0 0 -1218570461 1 -1073949596 -1073949588
```

Where did I go wrong because I'm expecting this output:

```
items before modification: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `sizeof` yields the size of its arguments **in bytes.** use `std::end(items) - std::begin(items)` instead. Better yet, use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: ...or use sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]), or sizeof(items) / sizeof(int), so you divide the size in bytes, by the size in bytes of an element - which produces the number of elements.

Comment: While it's useful to study "traditional" techniques so you understand how fiddly and error-prone they can be, make sure you don't use them for anything important.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(items)` = `no.of items` * `size of each item`. You probably wanted `no. of items only`, so divide it by `size of each item` as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int items[ 5 ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

 cout << "items before modification: ";
 for( unsigned int whatever = 0; whatever < sizeof(items)/sizeof(int);    whatever++ )
 {
  cout << items[ whatever ] << " ";
 }
}
```

Comment: Note to the OP: The `sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0])` trick only works with proper arrays. Arrays decays very often to pointers, for example when passing an array to a function, and doing `sizeof` of a pointer will give the size *of the pointer* and not what it points to.